# MongoDB C#: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using Azure CosmosDB's Mongo API in my C# .NET Core app, using the MongoDB driver.

I have a class which contains the following:

```
class MyModel
{
 [BsonElement("mydate")]
 public string MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

and when I try to retrieve the model (the table contains a `DateTime`), I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'DateTime'.

I have tried doing this:

```
 [BsonElement("mydate")]
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
 public string MyDate { get; set; }
```

but then I got this error:

> DateTime is not a valid representation for a StringSerializer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to convert it to

```
class MyModel
{
 [BsonElement("mydate")]
 public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did, but then I get `String '15/08/2018' was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

Comment: @MaximilianAst I don't have access to the database, the date is already inserted as it is... is there a way to format it later somehow?

Comment: @Eutherpyyou can parse the string date using var regDate = DateTime.ParseExact(yourdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: This would remove the error but return no result in case of querying the MongoDB